# std::atomic error: no ‘operator++(int)’ declared for postfix ‘++’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, stdatomic

I am trying to update an `atomic` variable through different threads and getting this error.
This is my code.

```
class counter {
    public:
    std::atomic<int> done;

    bool fn_write (int size) const {
        static int count = 0;
        if (count == size) {
            done++;
            count = 0;
            return false;
        } else {
            count++;
            return true;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    counter c1;
    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        while (! c1.fn_write(10)) ;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in line 8 `done++`.

> error: no ‘operator++(int)’ declared for postfix ‘++’ [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fn_write()` is declared as a `const` member function, inside which the `done` data member can't be modified.

Depending on your intent, you can make `fn_write()` be non-const:

```
bool fn_write (int size) {
    ... ...
}
```

Or, you can make `done` be `mutable`:

```
mutable std::atomic<int> done;

bool fn_write (int size) const {
    ... ...
}
```

Comment: I tried before to keep **fn_write()** to be non-const. But I got the following **error :  passing ‘const counter’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]** after which to fix this error, I read online and make my function as **const**

Comment: @Tushar Did you declare `c1` as `const counter c1;`? Is it your intent?

Comment: I declared **c1** as non-const. I don't want it to be constant.

Comment: @Tushar Then you shouldn't get that error. I tried it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DMNgHhswhz1jZRxQ).

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error using gcc and in my case it was because I'd forgotten to:

```
#include <atomic>
```